# $A\neq\emptyset$ is bounded above in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A$ does not contain a greatest element and if $x,y\in\mathbb{R},\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

$A\neq\emptyset$ is bounded above in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A$ does not contain a greatest element and if $x,y\in\mathbb{R}, x<y,y\in A$ then $x\in A.$

Then I think by the least upper bound property, $A=(-\infty,\sup{A}).$

I was wondering if there is a way to show $\exists a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $A=(-\infty,a)$ using elementary set theory.

Comment: No such sets exist, regardless of the condition regarding A containing its maximum. Any nonempty subset A of the real line such that a \in A and b < a implies b \in A cannot be bounded. In particular, it contains arbitrarily large negative numbers.

Comment: Do you mean that $A$ is bounded **above**? It can’t be bounded.

Comment: Yes, I mean $A$ is bounded above. I am sorry. Let me change my question.

Comment: Do you mean $A=(-\infty,a)$ instead of $A=(0,a)$?

Comment: @varpi Yes, I am sorry. I just changed the question again.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. If you know that $A = (-\infty, \sup A)$, then clearly $\exists \, a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A = (-\infty, a)$, since $\sup A \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B$ be the set of upper-bounds for $A.$ By def'n of $\sup A$ we have $\sup A=\min B\in B.$

(1). By def'n of upper-bound, if $b\in B$ then $A \subseteq (-\infty,b].$ And $\sup A\in B.$ Therefore $$ A\subseteq (-\infty, \sup A].$$

(2). If $\sup A\in A$ then by (1), $\; \sup A \in A\subseteq (-\infty, \sup A] \implies \sup A=\max A,$ contrary to the constraint on $A.$ Therefore $\sup A\not \in A.$ Therefore by (1), $$A\subseteq (-\infty,\sup A).$$

(3). If $x<\sup A$ then $x<\min B$ so $x\not\in B$ so by def'n of $B, $ $ \;x$ is not an upper-bound for $A$ so by def'n of upper-bound there exists $y\in A$ with $x<y$ so the constraint on $A$ implies $x\in A.$ Therefore  $$(-\infty, \sup A)\subseteq A.$$